# Figure in the table with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

How do I align a figure Tikz item at the top of the table? Its my result.

[image: my result]

[image]

I need the second alignment.

Comment: Do you mean “list” instead of ”table”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `baseline` key:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
```