# How do I vertically center a table and a circuitikz diagram?

Tags: subfloats, circuitikz

I would like a table and circuitikz diagram to appear to the left and right of one another, but I can't seem to get it to work with subfigures or subtables. What gives? Here's one of the ways I tried to get it to work. The table just ends up below the diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
 \begin{subtable}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,-1) to[battery] (0,2)
      to[ammeter] (4,2) -- (4,-1)
      to[resistor] (0,-1)
(0.5,-1) -- (0.5,-2)
      to[voltmeter] (3.5,-2) -- (3.5,-1)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{subtable}%
\qquad
\begin{subtable}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
Current & Voltage Drop \\
(mA)    & (mV)         \\ \midrule
500     & 198          \\
1000    & 381          \\
1500    & 581          \\
2000    & 824          \\
2500    & 904          \\
3000    & 1169         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: delete the empty lines before and after `\qquad`

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Completing your code snippets to a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful, so we know which document class you are using.

Comment: I should mention http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66109/aligning-a-figure-and-table-side-by-side and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11994/figure-in-the-table-with-tikz and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133732/placing-a-table-next-to-figure-align-table-vertically-centre and ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, images align (have their baseline) on the bottoms and tabulars are centered.  Both can be adjusted internally, or one can use \raisebox.  The following aligned their centers.  Also, \hfil and \vfil is how centering is actually done.

[image: align table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\begin{document}
\null\vfil% ceneter vertically
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}% reference
\begin{table}[h]
\hfil\raisebox{-0.5\height}{%
  \begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,-1) to[battery] (0,2)
      to[ammeter] (4,2) -- (4,-1)
      to[resistor] (0,-1)
(0.5,-1) -- (0.5,-2)
      to[voltmeter] (3.5,-2) -- (3.5,-1)
;
\end{circuitikz}}
\hfil%
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
Current & Voltage Drop \\
(mA)    & (mV)         \\ \midrule
500     & 198          \\
1000    & 381          \\
1500    & 581          \\
2000    & 824          \\
2500    & 904          \\
3000    & 1169         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do. Make the `tabular` align at the baseline too (like the image does by default) by using

```
 \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}cc@{}}    %% note [b]
```

[image]

Or align the circuit at the center of its bounding box (like the `tabular` does by default, you don't need to put `[c]` BTW):

```
\begin{circuitikz}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
```

[image]

This is more `tikz`ish way of vertically centering.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\begin{document}
\null\vfil% ceneter vertically
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}% reference
\begin{table}[h]
\hfil
  \begin{circuitikz}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
  \draw
(0,-1) to[battery] (0,2)
      to[ammeter] (4,2) -- (4,-1)
      to[resistor] (0,-1)
(0.5,-1) -- (0.5,-2)
      to[voltmeter] (3.5,-2) -- (3.5,-1)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\hfil%
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}       %% or use [b] position specifier as for the first case
\toprule
Current & Voltage Drop \\
(mA)    & (mV)         \\ \midrule
500     & 198          \\
1000    & 381          \\
1500    & 581          \\
2000    & 824          \\
2500    & 904          \\
3000    & 1169         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The subtable makes no sense here if you want it on top of each other. This is centered:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,-1) to[battery] (0,2)
      to[ammeter] (4,2) -- (4,-1)
      to[resistor] (0,-1)
(0.5,-1) -- (0.5,-2)
      to[voltmeter] (3.5,-2) -- (3.5,-1)
;
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
Current & Voltage Drop \\
(mA)    & (mV)         \\ \midrule
500     & 198          \\
1000    & 381          \\
1500    & 581          \\
2000    & 824          \\
2500    & 904          \\
3000    & 1169         \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear. I want the two to be left and right of each other, not above and below.